# Execute large number of query in MS SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I have approximate `10000000` query in a file for inserting data into MS SQL Server. The file size of that file is 3.09 GB.

Is there any way to execute this file.
In this file we have only inserting queries and that is not a backup file that's a simple text file with number of inserting query like below

```
INSERT INTO testcomment (commentid, createtime, requestid, activityid, activitytype, authortype, author, principal, messageid, sequencenumber, commenttext) VALUES ('0ef2b7afdb0648bf8fbcc7ad49bd9a3a', '2017-07-06 14:07:10.594', 'c9020d235b7a46fe81703945a55dc397', 'Activity12', 0, 'User', 'IDMProv', NULL, 'User_Task_Timedout', 1499364430594, 'User_Task_Timedout|System');
INSERT INTO testcomment (commentid, createtime, requestid, activityid, activitytype, authortype, author, principal, messageid, sequencenumber, commenttext) VALUES ('07e38a77b68b469abb55d5fa0560f3b4', '2017-01-11 10:23:40.873', 'ddaec20367be4247ac34c94249827b1e', 'Activity13', 0, 'System', 'IDMProv', 'System', 'Workflow_Forwarded', 1484148220873, 'Workflow_Forwarded');
```

So please suggest me an easy way to do this.

I am using MS SQL Server 2014.

Comment: You can try and execute the script from sqlcmd

Comment: 10000000 queries is a lot of queries.

Comment: You've tagged Sql Server 2005, 2008, 2012, and 2014... Which are you using...? I assume what you mean if you have a query that is (approximately) 10,000,000 lines long? Personally, I'd suggest using `sqlcmd`. I have a few queries that are around 1GB in size, and it has no problems doing the work.

Comment: @Larnu I am using MS SQL Server 2014.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu When I run my script using sqlcmd, it execute two time.

Answer (score 4):

I would use console for such task:

```
sqlcmd -S <server> -i C:\your_filename.sql
```

Comment: When I run my script using sqlcmd, it execute two time.

Answer (score 2):

You can run your entire script without opening it in SSMS by using sqlcmd instead.

[Here's a quick tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/sqlcmd-run-transact-sql-script-files) from Microsoft on how you can use it.

Or pretty much a copy-paste from MS website:

1. Open a command prompt window.
2. In the Command Prompt window, type: `sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql`
3. Press ENTER.

Comment: Do I have to update my txt file to .sql file with like this, `USE DatabaseName;
GO
INSERT INTO testcomment (commentid, createtime, requestid, activityid, activitytype, authortype, author, principal, messageid, sequencenumber, commenttext) VALUES ('0ef2b7afdb0648bf8fbcc7ad49bd9a3a', '2017-07-06 14:07:10.594', 'c9020d235b7a46fe81703945a55dc397', 'Activity12', 0, 'User', 'IDMProv', NULL, 'User_Task_Timedout', 1499364430594, 'User_Task_Timedout|System');
Go`

Comment: When I try `sqlcmd -S WIN-8B909VTGS9P.demo.local -i G:\logs\asd.sql` on my command prompt(Run as administrator) it gives me the error `Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : SQL Server Network Interfaces: The system cannot contact a domain controller to service the authentication request. Please try again later.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Cannot generate SSPI context.` but I can connect with SQL Management Studio with same Server name.

Comment: When I run my script using sqlcmd it execute the same query two time.